# Using AWS Comprehend Custom Entity along with generic Entity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-comprehend

Can We Override Custom Entity with generic AWS Entiy?

I Created Custom Entity But After that it was not identifying Aws Genreic Entity

Answer (score 1):

A custom entity recognizer will only identify the entity types specified during training. If you want it to be able to identify the AWS entity types, then you'll need to provide that in your training data. The alternative would be to use the custom recognizer in combination with the Comprehend one and either run a job with each, or use DetectEntities with each.